# Can't retrieve drawable ID

Tags: android

I'm trying to retrieve identifier of my drawables in my app, but it doesn't seem to work - only returns 0. I tried all possible ways, but none seem to work.

```
int firstImage = getResources().getIdentifier("@drawable/" + "norway.png", "drawable", BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID);
int secondImage = getResources().getIdentifier("norway.png", "drawable", BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID);
int test = getResources().getIdentifier("@drawable/rwanda.png", "drawable", BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID);
int test2 = getResources().getIdentifier("norway.png", "drawable", BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID);
```

What the heck am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.png` is never part of a drawable resource name. And, from the standpoint of `getIdentifier()`, `@` is not used. And it is possible that `APPLICATION_ID` is not the same as your package name, which is used for resource identifiers.

Use:

```
getResources().getIdentifier("norway", "drawable", getPackageName());
```

Comment: That fixed the issue. Thank you very much.